# How to prevent "Additional to" in email from being filled with same address as "To"?

Tags: email

What I observe is that Salesforce fills the "Additional to" field with the same email address as the "To" field, when clicking on an Email link. For example when sending a Quote PDF.

In itself it is harmless, the recipient will only receive one email, but it looks a bit silly and superfluous. I can't seem to find a way to disable this behavior, anyone here who knows how to prevent it?